# How can I invert the colors of a Word file?

Tags: microsoft-word-2019

I have a word file with lot of formatting in it like page color (Black) multiple light fonts with various formatting. Now I have to print it in black and white color. I tried to replace fonts and removed the background but the problem didn't solve as even after removing the background color there are still some portion of text that has black background (while making the file I copied that text with dark background from notepad++ and that same formatting has been copied by word, [here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3lkS.png) ).

So I thought it would be a lot better if somehow I can invert/negate all the colors of that word file ?
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: your printer might automatically do that if you select print grayscale. Try a print-preview to confirm.

Comment: @LPChip That didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Design >> Page colour >> Black
Now, Go to Home >> Press Ctrl+A >> Change Font color to White

You're Done